# How to define a “don't care” class in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss, cross-entropy

I have a time series classification task in which I should output a classification of 3 classes for every time stamp `t`.

All data is labeled per frame.

In the data set are more than 3 classes [which are also imbalanced].

My net should see all samples sequentially, because it uses that for historical information.
Thus, I can't just eliminate all irrelevant class samples at preprocessing time.

In case of a prediction on a frame which is labeled differently than those 3 classes, I don't care about the result.

---

How to do this correctly in Pytorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-to-use-ignore-index/5935), which was not google searchable, there are two options, both are options of the [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html):

### Option 1

If there is only one class to ignore, use `ignore_index=class_index` when instantiating the loss.

### Option 2

If there are more classes, use `weight=weights`, with `weights.shape==n_classes` and `torch.sum(weights[ignored_classes]) == 0`